# TaskStatus class has a method getPhase(). what does it return?(are they only map, shuffle, sort, reduce?)

Tags: hadoop

```
TaskStatus k = null;
TaskStatus.Phase CurrentPhase = k.getPhase();
```

Is above code true, If I want to know the current phase of one task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskStatus.java#TaskStatus.Phase)

`TaskPhase.getPhase` can return any of the following values depending on which phase the process is currently in

```
public static enum Phase{STARTING, MAP, SHUFFLE, SORT, REDUCE, CLEANUP}
```